# What's the difference between git stash and git stash save?

Tags: git

Can someone explain the difference between:

```
git stash
```

versus:

```
git stash save
```

?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

From the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash):

> Calling git stash without any arguments is equivalent to git stash
>   save.